# Python regex this specific string format

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract from the string the following:

Original string: `M 1,81 PRT 25 12 1988`

I want to extract: `25 12 1988`

Basically `2numbers|space|2numbers|space|4numbers`

I am struggling to do it, so far i got to this but my little experience with `regex` keeps me from finishing it.

Tried with this regex:

```
(?<!\S)\w+(?!\S)
```

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)\d{2} \d{2} \d{4}(?!\S)`

Answer (score 0):

This will return the captured data as a group, and will work regardless of the whitespace character used.

```
(\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{4})
```

Go to regex101.com and try it out.  It's a good way to build your expressions.

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty easy one:

`(\d{2} \d{2} \d{4})`

Quite self-explanatory. `\d` means a digit, and `{N}` means the count.

Comment: I don't know much of regrex, but, aren't you forgetting the brackets `()`?

Comment: Sure, if you need to have a capturing group, the brackets should be there!